# Using runtime variables in spock verification

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, spock

I am trying to write a simple test where I would like to verify mock call with some runtime variable. At the moment it looks like this:

```
class Spec extends Specification implements SampleData {

    EventBus eventBus = Mock()

    Facade facade = new Configuration().facade(eventBus)

    def "when the method is called an proper event is emitted"() {
        when:
            def id = facade.call(sampleData)

        then:
            1 * eventBus.push(_ as Event)
    }

}
```

But what I want to achieve is also to verify if the payload of the event was correct - which means that the event contains the `id`, something like this:

```
then:
        1 * eventBus.push(new Event(id))
```

Is it somehow possible to achieve such verification in Spock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the `Event` by stubbing the `push()` method on the `EventBus`.

```
def "when the method is called a proper event is emitted"() {
    given:
        EventBus eventBus = Mock()
        Facade facade = new Configuration().facade(eventBus)
        Event received
    when:
        def id = facade.call(sampleData)
    then:
        1 * eventBus.push(_ as Event) >> { Event event -> received = event }
        received.id == id
}
```

Comment: Isn't that unnecessarily complicated? If `Event` has a proper `equals` method, it should work like the OP suggested and this should not be necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately not @kriegaex, as the interaction is moved to before the `when` block, so it would be `...addInteraction(...addEqualArg(new Event(id)).build()); java.lang.Object id = facade.call(sampleData)` and thus will not compile. The only other solution that I can come up with is to influence the id that is generated through mocking, so that it can be defined in the `given` block.

Comment: Yes, of course. I shouldn't have commented on a question or answer I only gave a cursory glance while looking over my news feed. This is embarrassing. I am stupid and ugly. I thought the question was just about argument matching.

Comment: @kriegaex, ironically, I made the same comment about `equals` to the OP before deleting it when I realized the solution is more complex.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments, provided answer helped me a lot :)  - still I would rather expect something simpler from Spock :P